# Area 51 Questions per day - running out of questions on the topic?

Tags: discussion, area-51, beta-sites

I have been looking over some Area 51 proposals that are currently in beta. Most proposals have a good overall score on the 'statistics', except for **Questions per day**.

I have read the guidelines that indicate that such a thing is not too bad, as long as all the other statistics are good, after all, the websites need quality questions, not necessarily quantity.

But if websites that have been up over a year (or in some cases, two or three) and still can't manage to get over 5 questions a day (which seems to be almost all) would it not be some indication that people might have just ran out of new questions to ask?

And to add to that, if people have, in fact, ran out of questions to ask, what would be the purpose of maintaining the beta?

As example I give you [Genealogy and Family History](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502/genealogy-family-history), 
[LEGO](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10919/lego)
And [Poker](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3425/poker)

They all have good percentages answered, and the second one also has views, but all of them seem to have been abandoned over time.

I would like to know how other people see these and other proposals, what can be done to boost them back to life, or whether steps should be taken to remove them.

Comment: Ultimately, if the people aren't interested in running the site, the site can't launch. If it is abandoned, then it will show. As for how to spur interest, the best I can think of is to try again later.

Comment: The Poker site is a good example of a site that was probably too narrow to begin with and already covered by an existing site (Board & Card Games).

Comment: Some sites having a lot of views despite the lack of questions might mean that the few questions that are being asked are high quality questions that reach and help a lot of people. If someone's already asked it, there's no need to ask again after all.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't as much of a numbers game as those statistics might suggest, but I'm asked about this enough that I wrote a blog post about it:

[**Does this site have a chance of succeeding?**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)

The main takeaway is that five questions/day isn't necessarily "running out of questions." But whether the site is still viable depends on entirely on the subject, the quality, growth, and the overall engagement of the participants. Five strong, well-asked questions with great answers makes the internet a whole lot better than 50 questions poorly asked and answered.